# Xamarin.iOS project not building after Firebase.Crashlytics upgrade

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I try to build my iOS project I get the following error:

```
Could not decompress the native framework 'FirebaseInstallations.framework' from '/Users/user188959/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TestApp.iOS/cc2e7be6a53e530c6acb7d83641ed73c09b7e9dc20fc89349f358d22430aaf4f/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstallations.framework.zip
```

My iOS build Linker Behaviour is Link Framework SDKs Only. I have tried to delete bin & obj folders, clean & build and also restart Visual Studio, nothing seems to work and I really need to get over this hurdle. All help is much appreciated, thanks.

It only happens after my upgrade of Firebase Crashlytics from 3.14.0.3 to 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue.

Updating Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID and after that all Xamarin.Firebase.iOS libraries solved it for me.